# Usbip in Docker

Tags: linux, docker, usb, virtualization

1. I have a hardware dev kit on my desk attached to my Windows laptop via USB. The dev kit allows you to flash a chip via USB. I would like to expose this device to my server environment using usbip.
2. On my Windows PC I run a virtualbox with USBIP server. I have bound the hw dev kit. The server is listening on port 3240 which is forwarded by Virtual Box to the host (laptop) port 7023
3. Using SSH I login into my server. I have setup an SSH remote tunnel so that port 3240 on the server will sent requests to port 7023 on the laptop.

Summary

> USBIP server port 3240 --Virtual Box--> laptop port 7023 <--SSH -R :3240:localhost:7023

On the server this is working:

```
sudo /usr/lib/linux-tools-4.4.0-66/usbip --tcp-port 3240 attach -r 127.0.0.1 -b 1-2
dinne@vidar:~$ lsusb
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 04f2:b39a Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd
```

Now on the server I have a some Docker containers running. These containers have a development environment with which I can compile programs for the hw dev kit. And I would like to flash the compiled application to the dev kit.

Each user will have his/her own dev container on the server and a locally installed dev kit. So I would like to avoid using usbip to attach the virtual USB device directly on the server. Rather it would be ideal if the user could run usbip inside the Docker container.

Inside the Docker container I tried this:

```
sudo usbip --tcp-port 3240 list -r 192.168.96.101

Exportable USB devices
======================
 - 192.168.96.101
        1-2: Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd : unknown product (04f2:b39a)
           : /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:06.0/usb1/1-2
           : Miscellaneous Device / ? / Interface Association (ef/02/01)

sudo usbip --debug --tcp-port 3240 attach -r 192.168.96.101 -b 1-2

usbip: info: using port 3250 ("3250")
usbip: debug: /build/linux-tools-SJqEHJ/linux-tools-3.16.7-ckt20/drivers/staging/usbip/userspace/src/usbip_network.c:40:[usbip_setup_port_number] parsing port arg '3250'
usbip: info: using port 3250 ("3250")
usbip: debug: /build/linux-tools-SJqEHJ/linux-tools-3.16.7-ckt20/drivers/staging/usbip/userspace/src/usbip.c:141:[run_command] running command: `attach'
libusbip: debug: /build/linux-tools-SJqEHJ/linux-tools-3.16.7-ckt20/drivers/staging/usbip/userspace/libsrc/vhci_driver.c:242:[usbip_vhci_driver_open] available ports: 7
libusbip: debug: /build/linux-tools-SJqEHJ/linux-tools-3.16.7-ckt20/drivers/staging/usbip/userspace/libsrc/vhci_driver.c:71:[parse_status] port 0 status 4 speed 0 devid 0
libusbip: debug: /build/linux-tools-SJqEHJ/linux-tools-3.16.7-ckt20/drivers/staging/usbip/userspace/libsrc/vhci_driver.c:72:[parse_status] socket 0 lbusid 0000000000000000
libusbip: debug: /build/linux-tools-SJqEHJ/linux-tools-3.16.7-ckt20/drivers/staging/usbip/userspace/libsrc/vhci_driver.c:71:[parse_status] port 1 status 4 speed 0 devid 0
libusbip: debug: /build/linux-tools-SJqEHJ/linux-tools-3.16.7-ckt20/drivers/staging/usbip/userspace/libsrc/vhci_driver.c:72:[parse_status] socket 0 lbusid 0000000000000000
libusbip: debug: /build/linux-tools-SJqEHJ/linux-tools-3.16.7-ckt20/drivers/staging/usbip/userspace/libsrc/vhci_driver.c:71:[parse_status] port 2 status 4 speed 0 devid 0
libusbip: debug: /build/linux-tools-SJqEHJ/linux-tools-3.16.7-ckt20/drivers/staging/usbip/userspace/libsrc/vhci_driver.c:72:[parse_status] socket 0 lbusid 0000000000000000
libusbip: debug: /build/linux-tools-SJqEHJ/linux-tools-3.16.7-ckt20/drivers/staging/usbip/userspace/libsrc/vhci_driver.c:71:[parse_status] port 3 status 4 speed 0 devid 0
libusbip: debug: /build/linux-tools-SJqEHJ/linux-tools-3.16.7-ckt20/drivers/staging/usbip/userspace/libsrc/vhci_driver.c:72:[parse_status] socket 0 lbusid 0000000000000000
libusbip: debug: /build/linux-tools-SJqEHJ/linux-tools-3.16.7-ckt20/drivers/staging/usbip/userspace/libsrc/vhci_driver.c:71:[parse_status] port 4 status 4 speed 0 devid 0
libusbip: debug: /build/linux-tools-SJqEHJ/linux-tools-3.16.7-ckt20/drivers/staging/usbip/userspace/libsrc/vhci_driver.c:72:[parse_status] socket 0 lbusid 0000000000000000
libusbip: debug: /build/linux-tools-SJqEHJ/linux-tools-3.16.7-ckt20/drivers/staging/usbip/userspace/libsrc/vhci_driver.c:71:[parse_status] port 5 status 4 speed 0 devid 0
libusbip: debug: /build/linux-tools-SJqEHJ/linux-tools-3.16.7-ckt20/drivers/staging/usbip/userspace/libsrc/vhci_driver.c:72:[parse_status] socket 0 lbusid 0000000000000000
libusbip: debug: /build/linux-tools-SJqEHJ/linux-tools-3.16.7-ckt20/drivers/staging/usbip/userspace/libsrc/vhci_driver.c:71:[parse_status] port 6 status 4 speed 0 devid 0
libusbip: debug: /build/linux-tools-SJqEHJ/linux-tools-3.16.7-ckt20/drivers/staging/usbip/userspace/libsrc/vhci_driver.c:72:[parse_status] socket 0 lbusid 0000000000000000
libusbip: debug: /build/linux-tools-SJqEHJ/linux-tools-3.16.7-ckt20/drivers/staging/usbip/userspace/libsrc/vhci_driver.c:71:[parse_status] port 7 status 4 speed 0 devid 0
libusbip: debug: /build/linux-tools-SJqEHJ/linux-tools-3.16.7-ckt20/drivers/staging/usbip/userspace/libsrc/vhci_driver.c:72:[parse_status] socket 0 lbusid 0000000000000000
libusbip: debug: /build/linux-tools-SJqEHJ/linux-tools-3.16.7-ckt20/drivers/staging/usbip/userspace/libsrc/vhci_driver.c:105:[parse_status] exit
libusbip: debug: /build/linux-tools-SJqEHJ/linux-tools-3.16.7-ckt20/drivers/staging/usbip/userspace/libsrc/vhci_driver.c:311:[usbip_vhci_attach_device2] writing: 0 3 65539 2
libusbip: debug: /build/linux-tools-SJqEHJ/linux-tools-3.16.7-ckt20/drivers/staging/usbip/userspace/libsrc/vhci_driver.c:316:[usbip_vhci_attach_device2] attach attribute path: /sys/devices/platform/vhci_hcd/attach
usbip: debug: /build/linux-tools-SJqEHJ/linux-tools-3.16.7-ckt20/drivers/staging/usbip/userspace/libsrc/sysfs_utils.c:17:[write_sysfs_attribute] error opening attribute /sys/devices/platform/vhci_hcd/attach
libusbip: debug: /build/linux-tools-SJqEHJ/linux-tools-3.16.7-ckt20/drivers/staging/usbip/userspace/libsrc/vhci_driver.c:320:[usbip_vhci_attach_device2] write_sysfs_attribute failed
usbip: error: import device
usbip: error: query
```

It seems that open("/sys/devices/platform/vhci_hcd/attach", O_WRONLY) is failing.

```
sudo -- sh -c "ls -al /sys/devices/platform/vhci_hcd/"
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root    0 Mar 21 22:00 .
drwxr-xr-x 19 root root    0 Mar 21 21:21 ..
--w-------  1 root root 4096 Mar 21 22:00 attach
--w-------  1 root root 4096 Mar 21 22:00 detach
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    0 Mar 21 22:00 driver -> ../../../bus/platform/drivers/vhci_hcd
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 4096 Mar 21 22:00 driver_override
-r--r--r--  1 root root 4096 Mar 21 22:00 modalias
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    0 Mar 21 22:00 power
-r--r--r--  1 root root 4096 Mar 21 21:21 status
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    0 Mar 21 22:00 subsystem -> ../../../bus/platform
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 4096 Mar 21 21:21 uevent
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root    0 Mar 21 22:00 usb5
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 4096 Mar 21 22:00 usbip_debug
```

How to get an USBIP client working in a Docker container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i run docker with --privileged it seems to work.

Comment: Not sure why you were down voted, this also fixed it for me. You could also answer this forum question: https://www.virtualhere.com/content/error-when-useing-device where the manufacturer was wondering why sys was RO.

Comment: Also - I am on MacOSX running in "Docker Desktop for Mac" i.e. LinuxKit, so this is a cross platform solution.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem on kubernetes. It turned out that /sys was read read-only (even with --privileged). I solved it by adding /sys as a volume with host path (on docker, it's "-v /sys:/sys").